# I've had installed oracle java, then I removed but the oracle java options are still in the aplications? How do i remove them

Tags: 12.04, java, oracle

I had troubles unistalling oracle java but finally i did it (don't know how) but still the oracle java options are appearing in the dash home like Oracle java console and so on.
I'd like to remove them because i don't really have the oracle java installed anymore (i check in synaptics software manager).
I'm using 12.04.1 (Ubuntu version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions :

- Drag those Java Oracle options into the Trash of the Launcher (and empty the trash of course).
- Find the .desktop file related to it (probably in `/usr/share/applications/` or in `~/.local/share/applications/`) and delete the file.